# How to search a particular String using the XML Parse option in R

Tags: r

I am parsing DEF filings for a company and extract table from it which contains compensation data The table which contains this data has a String "Name and Principal Position" which is unique and helps me locate the table 
b = xpathSApply(a,"//table[contains(.,'Name and Principal')]") 
a is the HTMLParse of that page.
a<-htmlParse("sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/858877/000119312515333996/…)
 In some cases where the spacing is different in that string i get an error..i want to search "Name" "Position" individually and see which table they exist together which is unique

```
xpathSApply(a,"//table[contains(.,'Name and Principal')]")
```

I want the that if the table contains 'Name and Principal' or 'Principal Position' or another string.. it should show up..
Right now i can only use this string.. 
I am using XML and HTML Packages..

New to R, so excuse if it is stupid question

Comment: Please add more information. For example, provide a sample of the data you are trying to parse as well as the names of the packages you are using. your question is unclear and it is not possible to help without more information.

Comment: I am parsing DEF filings for a company and extract table from it which contains compensation data
The table which contains this data has a String "Name and Principal Position" which is unique and helps me locate the table

b = xpathSApply(a,"//table[contains(.,'Name and Principal')]")

a is the HTMLParse of that page.a<-htmlParse("http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/858877/000119312515333996/d95056ddef14a.htm") 

In some cases where the spacing is different in that string i get an error..i want to search "Name" "Position" individually and see which table they exist together which is unique

Comment: Using XML
HTML packages

Comment: Add this information to your question, rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? The `|` does an OR expression...

```
xpathSApply(a,"//table[contains(.,'Name and Principal|Principal Position|another string')]")
```

Comment: Nope this does not work.
Also i tried to make a vector of these words and then search the vector in the string.. 
Example<-c("Name","Position")
xpathSApply(a,"//table[contains(.,Example)]).. This also does not work